# Remove the word "Answer" from items in the search results

Tags: feature-request, search, ios-app

When looking at  the result list of a search, you can see the word "Answer" right before the answer's body, but no "Question" if it's a question:

> [image: QA list]

My request is to remove the word "Answer" as there is no need for duplicate information. The letter 'A' already says that post is an answer.