# 'Start a bounty' link color is just black, looks like a plain text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounties, hyperlinks

Why does the "start a bounty" link-text color look like simple text, not like a link?

> [image: start a bounty]

Also, the color for "start a bounty" link doesn't change when moused-over. (As it does do for other links, e.g. action links block below a question:

> [image: edit]

You can find a "start a bounty" link in any (?) question older than 2 days. E.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286651/339911).

Comment: The obvious (non)answer is that it looks like that because of the `a.bounty-link { color: #0C0D0E }` rule in the style sheet. But of course, that doesn't explain *why it's styled that way* to begin with.

Comment: Might be a bug, simple overlook by the developers when the design was changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a link now:

> [image]

and also changes color when hovered over:

> [image]

So, fixed?

Comment: Keep giving good answers here and the race with EL&U would be lost. ;)