# "question eligible for bounty in x days" link has an invalid HTML id

Tags: bug, design, bounties, hyperlinks

Under your own question, if it isn't old enough (2 days) for a bounty, a link is shown:

> [question eligible for bounty in *x* days](/help/bounty)

The ID of this element (`bounty-link bounty`) does not conform to the HTML standards as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70579/4751173), as it contains a space. This makes it impossible to select with a CSS selector.

[image]

I suspect the `id` *itself* is wrong, as the 'start a bounty' link (shown if it's actually possible to start a bounty) has `class="bounty-link bounty"` instead. This will have the additional effect of changing the color of the link from blue to black.

Comment: Most likely a developer didn't have enough coffee, and gave id instead of class.

Comment: Related [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287606/339911).

Comment: @alexolut yeah, definitely related. And Shadow Wizard already found the root cause :)